# Create an expression tree that calls an expression tree

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a property on a class

```
Expression<Func<Product, int>> predicate;
```

that will be assigned to different expressions throughout the application.

In a method called `GetProducts` I would like to retrieve Products from the DB using Entity Framework, using this predicate. I will then have a variable called `myInt` that I would like to use as the `int` parameter, that will then be assigned a value.

So I tried

```
dbContext.Products.Where(p => predicate(p, myInt))
```

but I got `Non-invocable member 'predicate' cannot be used like a method.` error.

It looks like I need to do some expression tree manipulation, to create a new expression tree, with `myInt` baked in it. How can I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `dbContext.Products.Where(predicate)`? You cannot invoke an `Expression<>` like it was a delegate. Besides, the signature is wrong; it takes only one argument. (To turn an `Expression<>` into a delegate call `Compile()`.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I can't use the predicate simply because the signature is wrong. I need to create a new expression with the correct signature that wraps the predicate, hence the question's title. Cannot use Compile, as Entity Framework only accepts non compiled expressions.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Should have read your question more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You defined `predicate` as a `Type` but you are using it as a method.

You can define a predicate in the following way:

```
private bool predicate(Product product, int myInt)
{
    //put your logic here
    return true;
}
```

You can also use lambda expressions:

```
product => product.SomeValue > 5
```

**Edit:**

```
Expression<Func<Product, int>> predicate = (product,val) => product.SomeValue > val;
var filtered = dbContext.Products.Where(predicate);
```

- Avoid using types when naming a parameters (i.e don't name an integer `MyInt`)

Comment: This won't work because it's not an expression, and Entity Framework will not be able to translate the method to SQL. Lambda won't work, because the subclasses that assign the property won't have access to myInt.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode 5! When the predicate is created, there is no way of knowing what myInt will be...

Comment: Where predicate is assigned to, there is no access to myInt. Please see my answer - I doubt there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

OK, got it.

```
ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product));
InvocationExpression inv = Expression.Invoke(predicate, prm, Expression.Constant(myInt));
var lambda = (Expression<Func<Product,bool>>) Expression.Lambda(inv, prm);
dbContext.Products.Where(lambda);
```

The key is `Expression.Invoke` that can invoke the predicate, using supplied parameters.

EDIT - After trying it, this only works with linq2sql - with Entity Framework it can't translate InvocationExpression to SQL. Instead, I used [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), as follows:

```
dbContext.Products.AsExpandable().Where(p => predicate.Invoke(p, myInt))
```